# Android ICS ping Issue after WAKEUP from suspend

Tags: android, tcp, ping, resume, suspend

We are working on a device which is running on android ICS 4.0.4 and 3.0.35 kernel. The issue we are facing is with device power management and network reach-ability. once device comes up from suspend mode it is not able to ping any ip address say 8.8.8.8 immediately. some times it take a minute or 2 minutes or sometime it becomes unreachable telling buffer space not available/ destination unreachable. but if we ping this device ip from outside it is responding and from device side also it starts getting ping reply from 8.8.8.8 what could be the reason for such behavior? and where could be the problem? we are clueless, the connection is through mobile data i.e. pppd. every thing seems OK in android UI it shows connected and maintains ip also, but not able to ping anybody after resuming from suspend. because of this issue device cannot browse immediately. where could be the problem, in Android? or kernel Power management? or PPP? If anybody have faced such issue and found any solution please help.

1. The use case is allow android device to go  into suspend mode, wait until it goes to deep sleep. wake it manually and ping any ip say 8.8.8.8 from device's android terminal.

**Expected**

1. Immediate reply for ping request.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether ttyUSB or ttyACM ports are working proper after suspend/resume

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with modem firmware. ttyUSB* points were use to hang, once the host M/C goes to suspend. After device resume it was not responding to any AT commands. So to prove the modem, we have experimented on ubuntu laptop. 
 Modem was connected to the ubuntu Laptop then allowed Laptop to go to sleep mode, after that when we resumed the laptop and issued AT commands at ttyUSB* there was no response from the modem. 
   So the point was clear that issue was with the modem not with our Android device. subsequently modem vendor corrected the issue in new firmware after that device retained its reachability even after host device goes to sleep and wakeup modes.